# Puppeteer page.evaluateOnNewDocument not running in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

Puppeteer page.evaluateOnNewDocument does not run in iframe other than in the iframe hosted locally.

Puppeteer script:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(window.location.href)
        }, 1000);
    }
    );
    await page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html");
})();
```

http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:5501/frame.html"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://pptr.dev/"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Output from chrome console: (nothing from https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page and https://pptr.dev/)

```
http://127.0.0.1:5501/sa.html

http://127.0.0.1:5501/frame.html
```